# What do I need to add to my Javascript to be able to show the hit counter from my DynamoDB table and API Gateway?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to be able to retrieve the hit counter from my DynamoDB table. I have an API Gateway, Lambda, and DynamoDB table all working with each other correctly. So far the code I have hits the API, triggering a count in the dynamo table, however the count on my site stays at 0. I'm very new to Javascript so I was hoping I could get some guidance for this. Here's the code I have so far:

```
const countEl = document.getElementById('count');

updateVisitCount();

function updateVisitCount() {
    fetch('https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        countEl.innerHTML = res.value;
    })
}
```

My Lambda Function:

```
import json
import os

import boto3

ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = ddb.Table(os.environ['HITS_TABLE_NAME'])
_lambda = boto3.client('lambda')


def handler(event, context):
    print('request: {}'.format(json.dumps(event)))
    table.update_item(
        Key={'path': event['path']},
        UpdateExpression='ADD hits :incr',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':incr': 1}
    )

    resp = _lambda.invoke(
        FunctionName=os.environ['DOWNSTREAM_FUNCTION_NAME'],
        Payload=json.dumps(event),
    )

    body = resp['Payload'].read()

    print('downstream response: {}'.format(body))
    return json.loads(body)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show your lambda function as well?

Comment: I edited my original post with the added lambda function, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

how often is the data on dynamodb updated?

the easy workaround is calling `updateVisitCount()` every N seconds.

You can try with this code. It will update value every 5 seconds

```
const countEl = document.getElementById('count');

function updateVisitCount() {
    fetch('https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        countEl.innerHTML = res.value;
    })
}

setInterval(updateVisitCount, 5000)
```

Comment: Hey I appreciate the help! So I want the dynamodb table to be updated when a user visits my web page. I think with the code you offered it updated the table at a constant rate and didn't track visitors. Am I right with that?

Comment: It also still doesn't change the actual viewcount on my website, it stays at 0

Comment: @nktanu, it seems the `visitCount` is the real-time value. You should not use rest API, you can use another way like `https://socket.io/` instead.